# Why is there less latency and jitter when there is additional high bandwidth traffic between two computers with Ubuntu 22.04 installed on them?

Tags: linux, network-interface, socket, buffer, real-time

I have two computers that are connected via an Ethernet cable with Ubuntu 22.04 installed on them. I have a client on computer A) which is sending UDP packets to a server on computer B) and I am measuring the latency and jitter of these packets in different scenarios. I have written the source code of the client and server in C, using the socket library.

When there is additional, high bandwidth traffic between the two computers on top of the packets which latency is measured, the jitter and latency is less than when I send the packets without that additional traffic:

- Round trip time without additional traffic: 0.556 ms
- Round trip time with additional traffic: 0.105 ms
- Jitter without additional traffic: 0.042 ms
- Jitter with additional traffic: 0.014 ms

It seems interesting because I would imagine less packets means less latency and jitter, but the results show otherwise. Can someone tell me what can be the reason? I suspect it has to do with buffer optimization, when more packets arrive, the buffer must be emptied more often but I am not sure. If that is the case, how could I configure the buffers in order to minimize latency?

Edit#1:
As suggested I tried to modify the parameters of my configuration for the NIC (ethtool -c):
[image: ethtool configuration]

I could only change the initial value of rx-usecs 3 to rx-usecs 1 us. I could not modify adaptive-rx and rx-usecs-low, I don't think they are supported by my nic.

Decreasing the rx-usecs value to 1 did not solve the issue, the latency difference of the two scenarios remained the same if not increased.

Increasing it to 5 and 10 us did not seem to help either.

Comment: What kind of network card do you use? While the answers seemed to have helped to mitigate the observance, do you know what has actually caused this difference in latency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reduce network latency and jittering, being said that it will always increase cpu load whatever the trafic and, in some cases, also decrease the throughput under heavy trafic :

**A/ THE DEFINITVE HAMMER : BUSY POLLING !** (Big fat warning, the less number of cpus you get, the more you will sacrifice on everything else.)

The idea is that rather than fire&forgetting some blocking `recvmsg` hence freeing your cpu for other jobs, eventually flushing your cpu caches, and eventually come back to your task after several context switches and softirq handlings… you loop into your task busy-waiting for data from the NIC.
As soon as data is made available in the buffer… it will be processed without any additional delay.

Please refer to `man recvmsg` and do read the part related to the **MSG_DONTWAIT** flag. Also note that you could achieve a similar effect opening your socket **O_NONBLOCK** and also note that the polling is also possible to be achieved by the kernel but I personally do not like the idea since… I get only 2 cores… ;-)

This being said, you'll definitely want to pin your task to one cpu, this will prevent possible task migration overhead and help keeping the cache hot.

Benefits of this method are immediate ! Reduction of latency & jitter to their minimum with no expense on throughput but… since there is no free lunch… highest possible cpuload.

**B/ LOW LEVEL NIC TUNING** (Interrupt coalescing, ring buffers, transmit queues… via `ethtool`)

**- Buffers :** In general and whatever the subsystem (network/sound/…) buffers are the ennemies of latency / jittering. So you'll want to reduce them to their minimum.
What is the value for the strict minimum ?
When, under heavy load, you start getting packets dropped and/or overruns (as reported by `ifconfig`)

**- Interrupt coalescing :**
Interrupt coalescing adds latency to the packet arrival time since the packet is in host memory, but the host is not aware of the packet until some time later. However, the system will use fewer CPU cycles because fewer interrupts are generated and the host processes several packets per interrupt.
Therefore it can be seen interesting to reduce coalescing to the minimum possible at, here the expense of cpu time AND throughput.

- OF course, this is not needed in case of *busy polling*.
- OF course, this gets very little effect in case of multiqueue network cards if you do not first ensure that their associated IRQs are evenly distributed on all available cores,
- OF course, It wont get any effect if your system is not running **irqthreaded** since the real work of the IRQ handling won't be achieved by a dedicated kernel thread following a real time scheduling policy.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer about busy polling helped me a lot. With busy polling I could get higher round trip time with additional traffic. 

Additionally, 

1) I increased the size of buffers based on this site: https://www.opensourceforu.com/2016/10/network-performance-monitoring/

2) I lowered the bandwidth of the NIC from 2500 Mbit/s to 100 Mbit/s to make it the bottleneck instead of my system:
sudo ethtool -s enp3s0 advertise 0x008

Comment: What if "jittery" periods always have the same span (around 5 seconds), and each of the bursts is almost always formed for around 200-300ms (so not very random)? Do you think the reasons you described can cause such a behaviour?

Comment: @tonso : "jittery period of the same span" ? I am not sure I understand your question. Do you mean **latences** ? and (because you write "same span") with small **jittering** ? In which case, running irqthreaded on oversized buffers could indeed well explain that. (I can elaborate)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant that there are series of short lags (as if server stops receiving and sending for 200-300ms), they appear randomly and always last for about the same time interval (5 seconds).

Comment: Is ifconfig reporting drops / overruns ? Do you get RT threads running on your system ? Link speed ?

Comment: No, zero everywhere. No RT threads, link speed is... decent enough I guess since the application RX/TX speed is well under 1MB/s. It's a KVM guest instance, so certain control options (such as `ethtool --pause`) seem to be non-available, and I'm trying to figure out if I should blame my tuning, or it's meant to be that way by design.

Comment: Wo! A KVM guest ! Things start immediately becoming too complicated for me. Sorry for that. I think you would better open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your network driver and -stack automatically switches from letting the card cause an interrupt whenever it has received an ethernet frame, or when it's done transmitting frame(s), to a mode where essentially, the kernel asks the card as quickly as it gets around to for whether there's anything to be handled.

Idea is that while intuitively, getting an interrupt every time a new packet arrives sounds like it's giving you low latency, handling interrupts requires some preparation, and thus, time. If you have a high-rate communication going on, it's almost certain that after you've handled a packet, done all the housekeeping of the kernel, there's a new packet waiting to be handled. So, the interrupt really only interrupts your work flow, and reduces the time you actually have available for *handling* the packet (rather than just reacting to the information that there is a packet).

You can control the behaviour of that using `ethtool -C`; check the man page of ethtool for the options it understands. You should check your current options using `sudo ethtool -c ${YOUR_ETHERNET_INTERFACE_NAME}`; I'd expect something like

```
Coalesce parameters for ${YOUR_ETHERNET_INTERFACE_NAME}:
Adaptive RX: on  TX: off
stats-block-usecs: 50
sample-interval: 20
pkt-rate-low: 0
pkt-rate-high: 0

rx-usecs: 0
rx-frames: 1
rx-usecs-irq: n/a
rx-frames-irq: n/a

tx-usecs: 0
tx-frames: 1
tx-usecs-irq: n/a
tx-frames-irq: n/a

rx-usecs-low: n/a
rx-frame-low: n/a
tx-usecs-low: n/a
tx-frame-low: n/a

rx-usecs-high: n/a
rx-frame-high: n/a
tx-usecs-high: n/a
tx-frame-high: n/a

CQE mode RX: n/a  TX: n/a
```

You can try setting the `rx-usecs-low` to some sensible value (in microseconds), or set `rx-usecs` and disable `adaptive-rx`. (Having adaptive RX is probably a good idea in anything that doesn't 24/7 do high-rate networking, with little to no downside.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I tried to modify the parameters you suggested. Unfortunately, they did not seem to help. For details please check my edited question. If you have any other advice please let me know.